# How to Index / Count nodes containing a subnode, in the format 1, 2, 3, 4

Tags: xslt

I'm trying to find a way to index nodes that contain a specific type of sub-node, and have them indexed starting at one and incrementing by one per each sub-node found. I tried using count() but this displays the position of the node in my code, not the index of the sub-node found. In other languages I would use a variable but this isn't an option in XSLT. 
 I have read some examples of a recursive count using templates, but I'm not familiar enough with XSLT to integrate it into my existing code.

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entry>
      <node>
           <subnodeA>test_subnodeA1</subnodeA>
           <subnodeB>test_subnodeB1</subnodeB>
      </node>
      <node>
           <subnodeA>test_subnodeA2</subnodeA>
           <subnodeB>test_subnodeB2</subnodeB>
      </node>
      <node>
           <subnodeA>test_subnodeA3</subnodeA>
      </node>
      <node>
           <subnodeA>test_subnodeA4</subnodeA>
           <subnodeB>test_subnodeB3</subnodeB>
      </node>
 </entry>
```

XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:template match="/">

    <!-- Initial usage -->
    <xsl:for-each select="node">
        <xsl:value-of select="subnodeA"/>
             <xsl:if test="subnodeB != ''">
                 <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>  
             </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>

    <!-- Second usage -->
    <xsl:for-each select="node">
        <xsl:if test="subnodeB != ''">
            <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>. 
            <xsl:value-of select="subnodeB"/>
         </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>
```

I want to display something like

```
test_subnodeA1 1
test_subnodeA2 2
test_subnodeA3
test_subnodeA4 3

1 test_subnodeB1
2 test_subnodeB2
3 test_subnodeB3
```

But using my method I can only get

```
test_subnodeA1 1
test_subnodeA2 2
test_subnodeA3
test_subnodeA4 4

1 test_subnodeB1
2 test_subnodeB2
4 test_subnodeB3
```

Some entries have a few nodes with no subnodeB and then a node with one, so my lists start at 3, 4 or 5.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for the simplest solutions at all that doesn't need any explicit conditional logic at all and any special axes/functions.

Comment: As @empo noticed, I initially hadn't understood correctly the problem. Since then I corrected my answer and the solution now is correct and still not involving any explicit conditionals, axes, `xsl:for-each`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case, you can get the position by counting preceding siblings

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::node[subnodeA and subnodeB]) + 1" />
```

In the second case, you just want **node** elements with a **subnodeB**

```
<xsl:for-each select="node[subnodeA and subnodeB]">
```

Here is the example XSLT. Note that I have switched from using **xsl:for-each** to using **xsl:apply-templates**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="text"/>

   <xsl:template match="/entry">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node" mode="initial" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node[subnodeB]" mode="second" />
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="node" mode="initial">
      <xsl:value-of select="subnodeA" />
      <xsl:if test="subnodeB != ''">
      <xsl:text> - </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::node[subnodeA and subnodeB]) + 1" />
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:text>&#13;</xsl:text>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="node" mode="second">
      <xsl:value-of select="position()" /> - <xsl:value-of select="subnodeB" /> 
      <xsl:text>&#13;</xsl:text>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This generates the following text output

```
test_subnodeA1 - 1
test_subnodeA2 - 2
test_subnodeA3
test_subnodeA4 - 3
1 - test_subnodeB1
2 - test_subnodeB2
3 - test_subnodeB3
```

Comment: This one worked well for me using the above example, and I can understand what's going on - Thank you. I did have to modify the "second" template for use in a more complicated situation to become: `<xsl:template match="node" mode="second">
 <xsl:if test="subnodeB != ''">
  <xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::node[subnodeA and subnodeB]) + 1" /> - <xsl:value-of select="subnodeB" /> 
 </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>` You put me on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

We can use count also applying templates directly on the interested node:

Given **subnodeA** as current node:

- `count(preceding::subnodeB[not(../subnodeA)])` count all preceding nodes without **subnodeA** (current shift)
- `count(preceding::subnodeA[../subnodeB])` count all preceding nodes with **subnodeB** (relative position - 1)

Let's see how it can work with repetition (subnodeA only, as subnodeB is trivial):

```
<xsl:template match="entry">

    <xsl:for-each select="node/subnodeA">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:if test="../subnodeB">
            <xsl:value-of select="
                count(preceding::subnodeB[not(../subnodeA)])
                + count(preceding::subnodeA[../subnodeB])
                + 1 "/>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
            <xsl:value-of select="'&#xA;'"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>
```

and with apply templates:

```
<xsl:template match="entry">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node/subnodeA"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="node/subnodeA">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <xsl:if test="../subnodeB">
        <xsl:value-of select="
            count(preceding::subnodeB[not(../subnodeA)])
            + count(preceding::subnodeA[../subnodeB])
            + 1 "/>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
        <xsl:value-of select="'&#xA;'"/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is one of the simplest possible solutions -- no `xsl:for-each`, no `count()`, no special axes and no explicit conditional logic at all**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*/node/subnodeA"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*/node/subnodeB"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[subnodeB]/subnodeA">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(., ' ')"/>
        <xsl:number level="any" count="*[subnodeB]/subnodeA"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="subnodeB">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(position(), ' ', ., '&#xA;' )"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(., '&#xA;')"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<entry>
    <node>
        <subnodeA>test_subnodeA1</subnodeA>
        <subnodeB>test_subnodeB1</subnodeB>
    </node>
    <node>
        <subnodeA>test_subnodeA2</subnodeA>
        <subnodeB>test_subnodeB2</subnodeB>
    </node>
    <node>
        <subnodeA>test_subnodeA3</subnodeA>
    </node>
    <node>
        <subnodeA>test_subnodeA4</subnodeA>
        <subnodeB>test_subnodeB3</subnodeB>
    </node>
</entry>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
test_subnodeA1 1
test_subnodeA2 2
test_subnodeA3
test_subnodeA4 3
1 test_subnodeB1
2 test_subnodeB2
3 test_subnodeB3
```

Comment: The reason why the other answers are less simple is because they manage the fact that the count for subnodeA is not positional and must be computed as by requested by OP.

Comment: @empo: Yes, I was still asleep this morning, thanks for waking me up. :). I have edited my answer now to provide a correct and still simplest solution.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - this has really opened up my eyes to what can be achieved in XSLT. I have a fair while before I'm working at this level ;)

Comment: @user891141: You are welcome :) Remember that in most cases the better solution is the simpler one.